# Unable to extract GUID from URL within header with regular expression extraction

Tags: regex, http-headers, jmeter

I'm having issue with extracting GUID from location in header. I tried following and it doesn't seems to extract at all.

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Length: 99
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Location: https://hello.com/books/category/cdeacb91af9f4faca842714c4ee9be45
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2015 22:29:37 GMT
```

I tried with regular expression and it just won't extract that GUID. In most scenarios, I was able to extract whatever I want with (.+?)

```
Location: https://hello.com/books/category/(?s)(.*?)$
Location: https://hello.com/books/category/(.+?)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try something like `Location: https://hello.com/books/category/([0-9a-fA-F]{32})` ?

Comment: That works Lucas, can you please reply as answer and I'll resolve. Btw, I tried ([0-9a-z-]{32}) and why it didn't work?

Comment: `[0-9a-z-]{32}` will match more than a GUID, it'll match every lowercase letter, but GUIDs can only contain hexadecimal characters (digits and A-F). Your pattern also includes a dash, which doesn't seem to be necessary from your example. But even if this matches *too much*, it should have worked for your example. It's surprising it didn't.

Comment: Thanks lucas. Yeah, I was scratching my head when your solution works and maybe I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a character class:

```
Location: https://hello.com/books/category/([0-9a-fA-F]{32})
```

`[0-9a-fA-F]` means all digits and letters between A and F, both upper and lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Your `(.+?)` regex will work fine if there will be right boundary provided.

Try changing it to

```
Location: https://hello.com/books/category/(.*)
```

It should do the trick

Also don't forget to change "Field to check" to "Response Headers" as regex will fail to lookup the "Location" header in the response body.

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide for more details.